# XOR Hex and ASCII

Tags: c, cryptography, xor

I have a 16 bit key (e.g., abcd) that represents hex values, and a 16 bit input (e.g., 0123) that I read in and stored in a character array. How would I XOR these together in C? I'm pretty stuck on this and don't really know where to start. I have to use C, and the key and input are read in from text files.

Comment: You probably need to convert the two hex strings to `uint16_t` values; apply the XOR operator to the two values; convert the resulting `uint16_t` value to a string once more.